# zend guard decode (not the same question)

Tags: php, decode, zend-guard

i know of old posts, or at least about old version of zend (<5, 4.0.1) but i want to know if the latest zend guard (5.5?) still is very easy to decode

like, did they updated the core a lot so its not easy anymore or its the same thing? there are tons of sites that can decode but is THAT easy in this last version?

btw, you dont need to post "no script can't be full protected since its not compiled and php need to interpret each file", thats not what i'm asking

Comment: Call Zend. Ask them. There is chat and contact data at http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Comment: im sure they will be pretty honest about their product being useless

Comment: If you dont trust Zend to be honest about their product, why bother at all? Zend Guard currently costs 600€ and you already know no script can be fully protected. If you want to know whether it's worth to invest that money (until someone comes up with a deobfuscator), ask Zend and confront them with your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=8599&p=28527